# Prototype Request (OnSuccess) Issue

Tags: php, prototypejs

I have the following lines of code in JavaScript (Prototype Library):

```
new Ajax.Request("/ajax/update", {
            parameters: {
                username: e.value
            },
            onSuccess: function (n, m) {
...
```

Now `n` returns as an Object, as it should. But `m` is null. How do I access or assign `m`? The code on my page 'ajax/update' is a simple PHP script:

```
echo 'MyUsername';
```

`m` should be an object like `n` so that I can access it like so:

```
if (m && m.spam === true) { ...
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect the m variable to be?

Comment: @TJHeuvel I updated the post to fill you in on that information.

Comment: What object do you expect? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the `onSuccess` event can return two variables? It doesn't look like it: http://prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request

If you want to return multiple variables you should use a json object: http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/json